# Changes to Angular Library not getting reflected when used in Another Angular Project

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a "Angular Library" and then use the same in another "Angular project". This is the requirement actually.

Following is what I have done:-

1. Created an Angular Project using --defaults option using Angular CLI.
2. Create an Angular library in the same project.
3. Angular library is build
4. Than I generated tar file using "npm pack" for the library project.
5. created another angular project(called client) using --defaults option.
6. Executed "npm install " to install the
   library project. "package.json" gets updated
7. In Appmodule, I added the reference of the module from the library.
8. In AppComponent, in ngOnInt(), I am using the method "log" from the service from the library. That methods logs passed value to console.
   9: Ran the project. Page gets loaded in browser and using dev tools, I could see the value on the console.

Now I go back to the Angular Library project and add a new method
called "Log2(msg:string)" which also logs to console.

Repeated the steps above to generate the tar file again.

Now in the Angular client project, I execute the command "npm install  so the new changes should get reflected.

Now I use the "log2()" in the AppComponent. I could add the new "log2()" method.
I fired "ng serve".
Page loads in browser. I see an error "this.srv.log2 is not a function" on console.

Not able to understand why the same error is coming.

I performed another test by building the client app and deploying the same on Web server. The works just fine without any issues.

the Angular Library was build using the following article:-
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/11/15/building-angular-library/

Any inputs would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you make a new version of the library with a new version number?

Comment: No.  This is just a Proof of concept for now to understand how the same would fit in our project.

Comment: Is that a mandatory requirement, I mean we need to change the version?

Comment: I'm guessing npm won't update your library unless you increment the version number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes like mentioned in the comments your new project will not understand there is a change in its existing tarball unless you make a versioning change, so for local dev and testing we have to keep changing the version of the tarball, but a better option for this would be using npm link which could save your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use [this example,](https://medium.com/@joosep.parts/create-an-angular-14-library-use-it-locally-when-developing-and-publish-the-package-to-npm-689ca2efdea8) the use of 'npm link' is described with clear details as to how to run a library on local. This helped me for the same problem I was facing and saved me from re-building the library manually each time I make a change it automatically gets reflected to the corresponding angular project.